# Pontwise convergence of indicator functions is the same as the convergence of their sets.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, pointwise-convergence

I'm studying probability theory, and I'm trying to proove the following proposition:

Limits od indicator functions

$A_n \rightarrow A  \Leftrightarrow I_{A_n}(w) \rightarrow I_{A}(w)$  , for all $w$.

Thus the convergence of sets is the same as pointwise convergence of their indicator functions

For this side   $\Rightarrow $ I was able to do it, by proving that:

$ \limsup I_{A_n} = I_{\limsup A_n}$

But I haven't been able to prove the other way ($ \Leftarrow$ ).

Comment: What does "convergence of sets" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that
$$
1_{\liminf A_n}=\liminf_{n\to\infty} 1_{A_n}=1_A=\limsup_{n\to\infty}1_{A_n}=1_{\limsup A_m}.
$$

Comment: But how does that imply that $A_n \rightarrow A $ ?

Comment: @flb You get
$$
\liminf A_n=A=\limsup A_n.
$$

Comment: I'm a bit confussed. How can i go from $I_{lim inf A_n} = lim inf A_n$?

Comment: @flb What exactly is your last question about?